# Prism: View First with multiple ViewModels

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container, prism, ioc-container

I'm using Prism with Unity IOC-Container in a WPF-Project. For all my other Views I'm using only one ViewModel per View. Because this View should be a Mask for both Input and Output of Data, I'd like to use two ViewModels.

For the current navigation to the View i use this Code:

```cs
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContentRegionName, typeof(Events).ToString());`
```

The Code Behind of my View:

```cs
public partial class Events : UserControl
{
    public Events(EventsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

One of the ViewModels:

```cs
public class EventsViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public EventsViewModel()
    {
       // Some Code
    }
   // Some other Code
}
```

I heard about ViewModel Discovery, where you give the Constructor of the View an Interface instead of an actual ViewModel. But i could only find exacly this much information.

```cs
// Example of such a Method
public Events(IViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = viewModel
}

public Interface IViewModel
{

}
```

My question is now: How do I navigate to the View and tell it wich ViewModel it should get as DataContext? I'm relatively new to programming and the MVVM-Pattern and english is not my native language so maybe I missed some Information. I would be glad if someone had an answer for this. Thanks in advance.

#### Edit: Workaround

I came up with a workaround wich works for me. I used the method `SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver()` from the `ViewModelLocationProvider` and customized it.

```cs
// Bootstrapper.cs
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    var window = (MainWindow)this.Shell;
    Application.Current.MainWindow = window;

    // Calling the method
    ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver(ResolveViewModel);
    var regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();

    window._regionManager = regionManager;
    globalRegionManager = regionManager;

    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegionName, typeof(StartScreen));
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegionName, typeof(Stock));

    window.Show();
}

// Property for handing over the desired ViewModel
public static Type DynamicViewModel { private get; set; }

private Type ResolveViewModel (Type viewType)
{
    string _viewModel = null;
    var name = viewType.FullName.Replace(".Views.", ".ViewModels.");

    if (DynamicViewModel != null)
        _viewModel = DynamicViewModel.ToString();
    else
        _viewModel = $"{name}ViewModel";

    var fullName = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(viewType).Assembly.FullName;
    var typeString = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, $"{_viewModel}, {fullName}");
    DynamicViewModel = null;

    return Type.GetType(typeString);
}
```

Then when I want to navigate, I hand over the ViewModel beforehand.

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Bootstrapper.DynamicViewModel = typeof(EventsViewModel);
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContentRegionName, typeof(Events).ToString());
}
```

A little tricky but it seems to work without any Exceptions.

If there is a cleaner way I'm alway happy to here it. :)

Comment: Why not navigate to the view model and resolve the view as datatemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some techniques for getting the view model for a view (view first).

View discovery in views code behind constructor

```
public EventsView(EventsViewModel view_model)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = view_model;
}
```

Explicitly newing up the view model in code behind constructor

```
public EventsView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new EventsViewModel();
}
```

[View model locator](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/ef1a2266905a4aa3e7087955e9f7b5a7d71972fb/Documentation/WPF/40-ImplementingtheMVVMPattern.md#creating-the-view-model-using-a-view-model-locator) in the XAML for the view

```
<UserControl x:Class="EventsModule.Views.EventsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventName}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As long as you register your view with the region manager using any one of the techniques below, any one of the above will work. Then navigate like you are doing in your question.

```
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegionName, typeof(EventsView));
UnityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(EventsView), typeof(EventsView).FullName);
UnityContainer.RegisterTypeForNavigation<EventsView>(typeof(EventsView).FullName);
```

The first will activate the view in the region and is usually seen in the module Initialize method. Those last 2 are for registering a view for later navigation. The last one requires the `Prism.Unity` namespace.

I don't believe that a view can have more the one view model since the view object only has one `DataContext` property on it. You may have to extend one view model to include everything you need. Someone may come along and prove me wrong on this. I have seen where a view model is shared with more than one view, but never a view having more than one view model.